# Multithreading best practicies

Tags: .net, multithreading

I'm writing dll, which does some things asyncronously.
some operations with databse for instance.
example:

```
(new Action(()=>
    {
    // database blablabla
    }
)).BeginInvoke((x)=>{}
              ,null);
```

i know, about threadqueue, about backgroundworkers, about Thread class and etc.
my question: what is the best way to do it? am i doing it right?
can it cause any troubles in future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have [an article on my blog](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2010/08/various-implementations-of-asynchronous.html) that discusses the relative merits of several approaches to asynchronous/background tasks. Asynchronous delegates are quite low-level.

I recommend you use a `Task`-based approach. Not only does this have the best support for aspects like error handling and return values, but it also sets you up for future success when the [async CTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/gg316360) becomes mainstream. If you have time, read through the [Task-Based Asynchronous Pattern](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=204847) document - it describes some things still being developed, but has excellent instructions for how to design a `Task`-based API.

Also keep in mind Marc's warnings about the database connection and thread safety. You can use task schedulers from the [parallel extensions samples](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ParExtSamples) to properly access the db connection while keeping a `Task`-based API.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a delegate's `BeginInvoke`, you are responsible for ensuring that `EndInvoke` gets called. I suspect that `ThreadPool` (or a custom work-queue / worker-thread(s)) would be a better idea.

Another thing to watch out for is the calling context; you will no longer have access to anything about the request, so any information (for example, the *site* if doing multi-tenancy) must be captured in advance.

Careful thread safety is obviously a concern, but impossible to give specific warnings about without a specific example.

Finally; be careful about the DB connection; connections aren't thread-safe, so you might want to ensure you have an **isolated** connection inside your worker, as you have no way of predicting what any connection in the calling context is doing; it could be disposed, or could be busy doing something. Don't use it.